# Evaluate similarity between two "encrypted" time series

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, data-privacy

Can you think of any way to evaluate the similarity between two time series without revealing any information on the time series ?

More precisely, considering two time series $x$ and $y$ of length 130 each, is there a way to get the minimum distance (using DTW for example) without reveling x or y ?

Recent work has been done on this topic using Homomorphic encryption but it performs very poorly (around 10 seconds to build and compute the minimum path on a $10*10$ DTW matrix)

Comment: The meaning of "privacy preserving" isn't in your title, although your post's body makes me pretty sure that you mean the [multi-party computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_two-party_computation) sense rather than the [differential privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_privacy) sense. ​ ​

Comment: Actually my case if a bit different from two-party computation. I have a non-trusted server that holds the two time series x and y in a hidden format (either encrypted or randomized or whatever). This server has to compute the minimum distance between x and y without knowing the clear values of x and y and returns only the clear or encrypted minimum distance. Does this make sense ?

Comment: So then, it's definitely not the case that "Everything is in the title.". ​ How related can the encoding procedures be? ​ (For example, can the encoders have a shared secret?) ​ Is selection of a similarity metric part of the problem? ​ Does the evaluation of that need to be exact? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes sorry, it's true that privacy preserving is not very accurate. In fact, the time series x and y will be obtained from a trusted client. Then yes, the client can have an encoder to encode both time series. The similarity metric would be Squared Euclidean distance.

Comment: Are they "paired up" a-priori, or will the scheme have to handle, for example, comparing x to y then comparing x to z? ​ ​

Comment: This will actually be a behavioral biometric authentication scheme. So one time serie is the user's template, that has to be "secured" by encryption or other means at user's registration and then stored in a database. The other time serie is generated when the user tries to log in. I have to find a way to compare (get the minimum distance = best alignment) of the two "encrypted" time series to allow or deny the authentication.

Comment: Something like [Ghostshell: Secure Biometric Authentication using Integrity-based Homomorphic Evaluations](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/484)?

Comment: Yes something like that. Except that, while they are dealing with vectors of 2400 bits representing Irises, I have to deal with time series vectors of length n. They just compare the template with the user's input and compare the result to a threshold. In my case, I have to align the two time series in order to have the minimum distance and then compare this distance to a threshold. This involves building a matrix of distances n². That is why homomorphic encryption is not an option for me.